# Error In Finding Number of Elements In Array (Perl)?

Tags: arrays, perl, hashtable

I am trying to write a program in Perl to find the number of elements in an array. (This array is supposed to be made up of files with "`.txt`" extension in the current directory. I then plan on using this array to read all "`.txt`" files into a hash.) However, I keep getting an array size = 0. I know that I have over eight "`.txt`" files in my directory, so wouldn't I have over eight array elements?

My program is as follows:

```
    #!/user/bin/perl
    my $readfdir = '.';
    opendir(DIR, $readfdir) or die $!;
    my @readf = glob(".*.txt");
    my $arrSize = @readf;
    print "array size = $arrSize\n";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your glob is most likely not what you think

```
my @readf = glob(".*.txt");
```

You are using what looks like a regex syntax, i.e. `.*` to match any string, but in a glob, that is `*`. So it should be:

```
my @readf = glob("*.txt");
```

Also, your opendir statement is quite redundant if you use a glob instead. Use either opendir/readdir OR a glob.

Answer (score 2):

```
glob(".*.txt");
```

You've got a "." at the start of the filename, are you sure there's files named that way inside your directory?

Answer (score 0):

Change your [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) specification.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @readf = glob("*.txt");
my $arrSize = @readf;
print "array size = $arrSize\n";
```

Also, there is no need for both `opendir` and `glob`.

Comment: Thank you greatly! Could you tell me how to mark this as useful or as another accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without using  `glob`.

```
my $dir = ".";
my @list_of_files;

opendir(my $dh, $dir) or die "$!";
for my $file (readdir $dh){
    push(@list_of_files, $file) if
        $file =~ /\.txt$/;
}

print join(' ', @list_of_files), "\n";
print "Number of files: ", scalar(@list_of_files), "\n";
```

Also, I believe `readdir` is not needed in your example. Eg. you can just `glob`.

This example will also just scan the given directory for txt files. If you want to find everything "below" the given directory, `File::Find` is great.

Comment: What does the "push" command do? Can you put all ".txt" files in the current directory into an array without using the "push" command? I apologize for this simple question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2174373 `push` adds elements onto the end of a list. See [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html)

Comment: This solution is bad for two reasons: (1) You read the whole directory into memory at once in your `for (readdir $dh)`. Use `readdir` in scalar context to use one entry at a time: `while(my $file = readdir $dh){}`. (2) Oh, all that `push`ing. You just re-invented the `grep` builtin: `my @files = grep /\.txt$/, readdir $dh;` could replace your whole loop, although this will load the whole directory listing into memory.

Comment: @amon Fair comment. For people *new*, as stated in OP, to perl. I don't see how this can be bad showing them `push`, and `for`. Are you going to say this solution is also bad because I `print` the files in the list, even though OP didn't ask?